# Not getting alert after entering a value in the text box and clicking the button

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, alert

[Output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izFcs.jpg)

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU0Yk.jpg)

Here I put my code and the output of my code, problem is I am not getting an alert as per the code.

Comment: Clarify better the need by explaining what is the issue and what you tried.

Comment: I want to get the value I entered in the textbox when I click the button as an alert, but I am not getting one

Answer (score -1):

In html, change `onclick()="getInputValue();"` to `onclick="getInputValue();"`

Comment: I changed now, still not getting the alert

Comment: Problem solved!!. Instead of getInputValue(), I used getInputValue(); . The end semi colon was the problem.